# SQL: Select distinct one column but include all fields

Tags: sql

How can I select distinct one column (user) and then output the rest of the fields based on this one column?

Input:

```
  user     age      country
--------------------------------
  Tom      34        US
  Tom      32        EN
  Dick     29        MX
  Dick     29        DE
  Harry    15        CA
```

output (distinct user column, and pick one row to output for rest of fields):

```
  user     age      country    count
--------------------------------------
  Tom      34        US         2
  Dick     29        MX         2
  Harry    15        CA         1
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: How do you decide which country to include in the output?

Comment: the rest of the fields (age, country) are just to pick any random row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT USER, AGE, MAX(COUNTRY), COUNT(*) 
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY USER, AGE
```

You could try changing the `MAX` for a `MIN`. No need for a `DISTINCT` here.
You could use some data format like `SUBSTRING`, but I'm not sure if the rest of the data will always be like that US and USS etc. Buy if you have more than 2/3 or if the changes start beyond a specific character you may encounter some wrong query results.

**According to comments and updates.**

```
SELECT USER, MAX(AGE), MAX(COUNTRY), COUNT(*)
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY USER.
```

Comment: the thing is AGE, COUNTRY is different, so how do I query for a distinct USER in this case?

Comment: it's not making sense or I'm not following. Tom has 2 ages (inexistent) or there are 2 Toms. One with 32 and the other with 34. If that's the case, then you don't have to count 2 on TOM because it's 2 toms. You want to know how many TOMs are out there? but why do you place then in US if one of them is from EN?

Comment: there are two different TOMs, but I'm only curious in aggregating the count for people named TOM in general, the rest of the fields are just selected randomly

Comment: thanks! I'm confused at how you're using the MAX() function though -- is it a hack to get around what my requirements are?

Comment: It's a way of getting just ONE value for those fields when you actually have more than one. All is valid as long as it fits your requirements. But remember, if you're not going to use those fields (age, country) then there's no need to query them. Play around with the query and see what fits you the most. And don't forget to mark the answer as the right one, it may help other people with the same doubt. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT user, age, country, COUNT(*) AS c_rec FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT user, age, SUBSTRING(country, 1, 2) AS country FROM yourTable
) T
GROUP BY user, age, country
```

Comment: get substring from field country: first param your field country, second param - startIndex third param length